# Get read and analyze permission in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created my google service account using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

Now I want to ask for read and analyze permission from a website in order to do some data analytics. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the service account (with an email like quickstart@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com) must be granted (at least) read permissions in the corresponding Google Analytics settings. Consider checking Analytics permissions [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en)